# magento 2.3.1 - Invalid template file

Tags: magento2, error, product-page, custom-theme

I been working on new webpage recently and got unfortunate error, when I click on a product in catalog page i get this error:

```
 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Magento_Catalog::product/view/product_info_main.phtml' in module: 'Ves_Themesettings' block's name: 'ves.product.info.main'

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Magento_Catalog::product/view/product_info_main.phtml' in module: 'Ves_Themesettings' block's name: 'ves.product.info.main'
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:668]
#2 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#3 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:533]
#4 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#27 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#28 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#29 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#30 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#31 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#32 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#33 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#34 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#35 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#36 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#37 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#38 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#39 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#40 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#41 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#42 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:954]
#43 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#44 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#45 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#46 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:494]
#47 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php:258]
#48 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php:171]
#49 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#50 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#51 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#52 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:130]
#53 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:140]
#54 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#55 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:258]
#56 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

Any helps would ba highly appreciated . thank you

Comment: `in module: 'Ves_Themesettings' block's name: 'ves.product.info.main'` was the block declared properly? Is there code to feed the block? I'm no expert, but sounds like a step was skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Please check `Ves_Themesettings` module XML file, you had declared `ves.product.info.main` block. 
You may be added a wrong template file there..

```
'Magento_Catalog::product/view/product_info_main.phtml'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all with the help.
Theme 2.3.x folder was missing product_info_main.phtml. and another file that caused an error. I managed to use older file from 2.0 folder. I will be contacting theme's author for update.

Thank you again